# Android WebView and Market url

Tags: android, url, webview, google-play

I use a webview to navigate my site. My site contain Market url.
I try to launch Playstore App when Market url is click (Code below) but the App open the last open App not Playstore.
If I come back and reopen my App, Playstore is open in my webView.
I need help, Thanks.

```
    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              if (url.startsWith("market://"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                 }
                else{
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                    }

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Unable to open URL\nPlease Activate WiFi or MobileData and Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

I solved the problem with this code change. Work perfect for me. Open Market from any market:// url

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url != null && url.startsWith("market://")) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the market urls correctly specified in your site. Are the urls in the correct format that starts with "market://" instead of "http://"

Comment: Yes url is in the Market format "market://" If i navigate my site in the browser and click the url playstore App open correctly

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check for Play Store's existance on the user's device. If Play Store is not enabled then open the store in your webview, else open the store app.

```
 final String appPackageName = yourPackagesName;
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + yourPackagesName)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + yourPackagesName)));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks George but this solution don't work for me. In my site i have various market link so i can't use string "yourPackageName" Any alternative solution?

Comment: Depending on the URL the user clicked, you will replace the `yourPackageName` string accordingly. Can you show us an example of how you format your URL's? If you mention the package in your URL you will be able to extract the package's name from there and set  it as the value of `yourPackageName`.

Comment: This is one of the Url i have in my site: "market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm&hl=en" (is an app i suggest). If i navigate my site in the Android Browser, click on the url open correctly Playstore but in the webview don't work.

Comment: The `com.google.android.apps.adm` is the Application's package name. You can assign that string on `yourPackageName`. When you say that in webview doesn't work what do you mean? Do you get an error?